# NSComparator changes behaviour while sorting NSArray when ARC is enabled

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, automatic-ref-counting, comparator

I am using NSComparator to sort objects in NSArray. When the code is not ARC enabled then comparator gives different results to when code is ARC enabled.

Following is my Code snippet:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedToolsInfoArrayWithKey {
    NSArray *aReturnVal = nil;
    NSArray *aToolsInfoArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ToolsData" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

`aReturnVal = [aToolsInfoArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)^(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
    [[a valueForKey:@"selectionCount"] compare:[b valueForKey:@"selectionCount"]];
}];

[aToolsInfoArray release];
return aReturnVal;`

}

This same method is written in Non-ARC code where I need the same kind of sorted array, Note that, my requirement is I need to sort the same array picked from same pList file in two different files, one of the file is ARC enabled while other file isnt ARC enabled.
But when I am doing that, I am getting exactly opposite sorting order and when I disable the ARC , the problem is solved.

I am not being able to understand the logic behind different behaviour of NSComparator to sort arrays in ARC and non-ARC enabled files.

Thanks..

Comment: Update your question with a few entries of your plist file so we can see what you are working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't `return` a value from your comparator block:

```
aReturnVal = [aToolsInfoArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
    NSDictionary *adict = (NSDictionary *)a;
    NSDictionary *bdict = (NSDictionary *)b;
    return [[adict objectForKey:@"selectionCount"] compare:[bdict objectForKey:@"selectionCount"]];
}];
```

(plus use `objectForKey` rather than `valueForKey`, which is the KVC accessor).

**EDIT** Missed the block syntax you were using is incorrect too (thanks to @Ivan Genchev).

Comment: Good catch on the `return`. But wouldn't the lack of a `return` cause a compiler error?

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I would expect it to.  I have assumed the OP has posted his actual code, though...

Comment: Just tried that and it doesn't cause an error, doesn't cause even a warning because he's casting the block to `NSComparator`

Comment: @rmaddy See `NSObjCRuntime.h` and `typedef NSComparisonResult (^NSComparator)(id obj1, id obj2);` in particular.

Comment: @IvanGenchev Nice catch.  Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-on to the answer by "trojanfoe", you have the wrong syntax for the block. You need:

```
aReturnVal = [aToolsInfoArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *a, NSDictionary *b) {
    return [[a valueForKey:@"selectionCount"] compare:[b valueForKey:@"selectionCount"]];
}];
```

Let Xcode's code completion fill all of that in for you. It avoids the kind of mistakes you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NSSortDescriptor` to sort your array.

```
NSArray *testArray = @[@{@"selectionCount":@"3"},
            @{@"selectionCount":@"1"},
            @{@"selectionCount":@"7"},
            @{@"selectionCount":@"2"}];
NSLog(@"testArray: %@", testArray);
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"selectionCount" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedTestArray = [testArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
NSLog(@"sortedTestArray: %@", sortedTestArray);
```